# Where should I use OnClickListner in firebase adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am retriewing data from firebase real time database and upon clicking a new activity will be opened which will show Name, blood group and other information of the users. I want to know where should I have an OnClickListner in my recyclerview i.e. ViewHolder class or in OnBindViewHolder (Adapter). What are the pros and cons of both. Below is my code Thank You all

**Adapter**

```
public class personAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<
        person, personAdapter.personsViewholder> {

    public personAdapter(
            @NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<person> options)
    {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void
    onBindViewHolder(@NonNull personsViewholder holder, int position, @NonNull person model)
    {
        
        holder.firstname.setText(model.getFirstname());
        holder.bloodgroup.setText(model.getBloodgroup());
        holder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public personsViewholder
    onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view
                = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.person, parent, false);
        return new personsViewholder(view);
    }

    static class personsViewholder
            extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView firstname, bloodgroup, phone;
        public personsViewholder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            firstname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
            bloodgroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bloodGroup);
            phone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class person
{
    private String firstname;
    private String phone;
    private String bloodgroup;

    public person(String firstname, String phone, String bloodgroup) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.bloodgroup = bloodgroup;
    }
    public person() {}

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getBloodgroup() {
        return bloodgroup;
    }

    public void setBloodgroup(String bloodgroup) {
        this.bloodgroup = bloodgroup;
    }
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with firebase. I suggest removing that dependency so you can focus just on RecyclerView and how it owrks.

Comment: Also, what are you adding the OnClickListener to? Is there a button in each row in the RecyclerView? Or is there a single button in the Activity which contains the RecyclerView? Or is this a listener for when you click on a row in the RecyclerView?

Comment: It'll be a listner on each row.

Comment: I want to know which is the best place to use it and why